# Recalling Variable Issue (involving geolocation)

Tags: javascript, var

I can't work out why `console.log(latitude)` isn't working outside of the `if` statement. I can recall `latitude` in the console so its value is being updated. My guess then is that `console.log(latitude)` is being run before `latitude's` value is changed but my solutions to ensure the `if` statement finishes first so far haven't worked. I've tried debugger too. Any help is much appreciated! (I hope I haven't overlooked something very simple!)

```
var latitude = "" ;
var longitude = "";

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      latitude = position.coords.latitude;
      longitude = position.coords.longitude;
      place.textContent = ("latitude: " + latitude + "  longitude: " + longitude);
    });
  }

  console.log(latitude);
```

Comment: because it is asynchronous. It is like ordering a delivery pizza, outside of it, you made the call and you try to eat it.

Answer (score 1):

Callback is asynchronous. Hence the console.log for `latitude` would return you `undefined`. If you want to access `latitude` after your calculation (inside the callback) then you need to do your code snippet bit differently. Something like:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      latitude = position.coords.latitude;
      longitude = position.coords.longitude;
      place.textContent = ("latitude: " + latitude + "  longitude: " + longitude);
      fn(latitude,longitude)
    });
```

Then you can get the last calculated value inside the `fn` function:

```
fn(latitude,longitude) => {
   //use the logic here
}
```